# Редиректы нестандартные для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Добрый вечер.

Возник следующий вопрос: 
на сайте сейчас сделали свои доработки и есть контент, который выводится с помощью параметров такого плана:

```
site.com/?country=france
```

или

```
site.com/?country=france&city=paris
```

Я хочу чтобы в первом варианте по ссылке https://site.com/france.html показывалась страница site.com/?country=france, но адрес в строке браузера оставался https://site.com/france.html

во втором случае, чтобы по ссылке

```
https://site.com/france/paris.html
```

открывалась страница site.com/?country=france&city=paris, но адрес показывался

```
https://site.com/france/paris.html
```

Подскажите, можно ли так сделать? Если да, то каким образом это реализовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Можете подсказать как быть в моем случае?
возможны варианты
/ru/country_name.html
/ru/country_name/city_name.html
/ru/country_name/city_name/place_name.html

ru может также меняться на en